# `is not true` does not work currectly in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `flaw` and `userdata`. There are `uid` column in `flaw` table and `FlawId`, `IsDeleted`(can be null) columns in `userdata` table.
I want to get all flaw not deleted by user using following sql:

```
select *
from flaw f
left join userdata `user` on f.uid = `user`.FlawId 
where `user`.IsDeleted is not true;
```

But the result only contains `flaw` rows that **has corresponding rows in `userdata`** and the `IsDeleted` value is not true.

For example: If `flaw` table contains:

```
uid 
1
2
3
```

and `userdata` contains :

```
FlawId | IsDeleted
1      | null
```

Then the sql above will only return:

```
uid | FlawId | IsDeleted
1   | 1      | null
```

But what I expect is:

```
uid | FlawId | IsDeleted
1   | 1      | null
2   | null   | null
3   | null   | null
```

Edit1:
I have tried move condition in WHERE clause to ON clause, then it work as expected. I want to know the reason of this wired behavior. I'm using mysql 5.7.36.

Edit2:
As SelVazi said in comment, this is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67732)

Comment: That is exactly how the SQL you have written should behave. You specified `LEFT JOIN` and that is exactly what you got.

Comment: @user207421 `left join` will generate empty `userdata`  row in results for each `flaw` row, so there should be 3 rows satisfy condition, but only 1 row returned.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? See this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdZkgqjtuxVEj9hp9sQjsX/1  It works as expected when run with mysql 8 but only returns 1 row when executed with mysql 5.7

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you suer that the `not true` condition is to blame here?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried move condition in WHERE clause to ON clause, then it work as expected.

Comment: @derpirscher I use mysql 5.7.36

Comment: Please keep in mind that MySQL 5.7.36 is pretty outdated. Also, please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @derpirscher Is it a bug in mysql5.7?

Comment: @AlpacaMan Honestly I don't know, because I never really used mysql. But it seems to be a problem with the `where` clause in the rows where no userdata can be matched. Because if you remove the `where` all three expected rows are returned

Comment: This is a bug, Have a look here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67732

Comment: @user207421 For a `LEFT JOIN` with the left table containing 3 rows, I'd expect the result to contain at least three rows as well (as long as the `WHERE` is not filtering them away -- which it currently is because of a bug in mysql 5)  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the

```
where `user`.IsDeleted is not true;
```

condition (at least in MySql 5.7, seems to work in MySql 8). You can work around it like this

```
select f.flawid, u.isdeleted
from flaws f left join users u on f.flawid = u.flawid
where u.isdeleted is null or u.isdeleted = false
```

See also this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdZkgqjtuxVEj9hp9sQjsX/3

Answer (score 0):

Left join behaves like an inner join and returns all rows from the left side that have matching rows on the right side.

Consider using outer join to return all rows instead: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-outer-join/

Comment: In a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the `OUTER` keyword typically is optional and any `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` is an `OUTER` join per default. Or citing from the page you linked: "*The left join operation returns all record from left table and matching records from the right table. On a matching element not found in right table, NULL is represented in that case.*"